# Looking for a method to offer Order Sample Button to be display in particular categories

Tags: sample

I am wanting to place a "Order Sample" button underneath the price in my product page. Can anyone help? I need it to be placed under products using the category_id. There will be several categories needing this button.

Comment: Placing a button is one thing, but what should it do?

Comment: I am wanting this to add the product to the checkout but adding SAMPLE at the beginning of the description and also adding SAMPLE to the SKU. only one sample per product aloud and for it to show in products only (possibly products within specific categories. The shipping wight must be set to 0 as the price also.

Comment: I have installed this mod https://gist.github.com/WazzaJB/8083094 - It does work but cannot get it to display in certain categories and it also add a product to my database.